# How to undo a "lerna link convert"?

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

From the [Common devDependencies](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#common-devdependencies) doc:

> Most `devDependencies` can be pulled up to the root of a Lerna repo with lerna link convert

It will pull up my `devDependencies` from the `package.json` file of each package to the root `package.json` file.

How can I undo this operation?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no undo operation built into Lerna, so your next best solution would be to use Git (or other VCS tool) to revert the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file changes.